# MYSQL DELETE multiple row doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is delete.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE memberid IN ('".$id."' )";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully" ;
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}


$conn->close();


}
?>
```

this is home.php

```
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "select memberid from table group by memberid having count(*) > 5";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Member ID: " . $row["memberid"]. " | <a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='deleteId(".$row["memberid"].")'>reset</a><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();



<script>
function deleteId(id)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
        {
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "delete.php?id=" +id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    //window.location.reload();

}

</script>
```

I'm trying to delete multiple row in a table by onclick from home.php unfortunately it doesnt work at all.

in the table row recorded many same memberid, so i'm trying to call by memberid and delete all of them in 1click

I'm new in php and mysql.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: $sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE c ='$id';

Comment: check it once 
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE c =$id ";

Comment: You need to show us the value of id but my guess is if you are trying to do an in, you need to separate each value and have quotes around them - at the moment, you have quotes around the whole id object, it seems you need to split the ids and put quotes around each one separately

Comment: Show us how you pass multiple rows?

Comment: okay.. is like that.. a table with column C and C=memberid. That mean in the table row may have many of the same memberid i'm trying to DELETE the same memberid in different row by using onclick from home.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE c ='$id'";
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower the OP and future researchers.  Please improve this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$idArr = explode(",", $id);
$idStr = implode("','", $idArr);
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE c IN ('$idStr' )";
```

Also, in your client side code,

Make sure that the **id** in **deleteId()** is alerting 012345 instead of 12345. Otherwise, convert the integer to string before calling deleteId().

Comment: Can you try echo $idStr and tell me what is the result?

Comment: is the c data start from 0 can affect to delete? let say is the column data is 012345, but i try to echo $idStr i got this 12345

Comment: Yes sure. It will affect.  But what is the column datatype of id in mysql table?

Comment: a phone number, some may start with 0 so any other way to fix this problem? Thanks you alot

Comment: In you client side script, Can you alert id in deleteId() function?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending in one id, so no need for using IN(), normal `id = ?` will delete all rows with that id. But you need to use bind parameters to stop someone from sending in something like `1 or 1=1` to delete all the rows in your table, don't trust the input even if it is sent from your javascript